# Do both mobile-sdk and onboard-sdk need internet connection when using?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm considering using mobile-sdk and onboard-sdk with matrice 600 pro.
I have 2 questions.

Both of mobile-sdk and onboard-sdk try to check their register to developer server(developer.dji.com).

Question 1:
Does this mean that I can not use both sdks without internet connection?
(Sometimes I want to use drone at place with no internet connection)

Question 2:
Is onboard-sdk's checking path like below? :

onboard -> flight controller -> transmitter -> 
mobile phone -> internet -> dji developer server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Registration (MSDK) and Activation (OSDK) are one time events - and pretty much the same things. After that, you don't need internet connection to use your aircraft. MSDK caches the value received from the server, OSDK get activated at the firmware level.

As a matter of fact, the SDKs were built (years ago) with in mind the fact that users would use a wifi tablet as mobile device outdoors - so without internet connection.

2/ Yes-ish. There is an Receiver & RC in between the transmitter and mobile phone if you want to be pedantic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your answer is very helpful for me!